# Error in getting values from python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpreter

I've created a python dictionary

```
user = input('enter a letter: ')
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
print(d.get(d))
```

I run that and enterned

```
a
```

But I always get an error like this

```
er a letter: a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

[Program finished]
```

Help me to slove!

Comment: How about `d.get(user)` instead?

Comment: Sorry i haven't got it, i'm new on this field. : (

Comment: All the answers suggest the same thing. Your objective is to look up the user in the dictionary. `d.get(user)` does that. `d` is the dictionary, `user` is the key you want to look up. `d.get(d)` tries to use the whole dictionary as a key. `d` is a dictionary (data type `dict`). Dictionary keys use a technique called "hashing" for fast lookup, but Python can't hash an entire dictionary.  In your case, the value you are looking up should be either 'a', 'b', or 'c'. You are telling it to look up `{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the variable with user's input:

```
user = input('enter a letter: ')
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
print(d.get(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user = input("enter a letter: ")
d = {"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3"}
print(d.get(user)) #user instead of d
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for dictionary in dictionary.
Use this:

```
user = input('enter a letter: ')
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
print(d.get(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `d.get(user)` or use `d[user]` instead

```
user = input('enter a letter: ')
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
print(d.get(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

well I got my answer, thanks to all of you for helping me. It's getting accessing dictionary data inside a dictionary. So the solutions is :-

```
user = input('enter a letter: ')
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c':'3'}
print(d.get(user))
```

Thanks again to all of u ;)